# CollectionViewSource with DataGrid produces BLACK control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to sort (descending) a property within a DataGrid. For whatever reason, the code below produces a black background.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedStations" Source="{Binding Stations}">
   <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="StationNumber" Direction="Descending"/>
   </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ., Source={StaticResource SortedStations}}"/>
```

Is there something that I am missing?

*** EDIT ***

ViewModel Code:

```
public class StationsViewModel
{
   public IList<IStation> Stations { get; set; }

   public StationsViewModel()
   {
       Stations = new BindingList<IStation>();
       Stations.Add(new Station() { StationNumber = 10 };
       Stations.Add(new Station() { StationNumber = 2 };
       Stations.Add(new Station() { StationNumber = 7 };
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like incorrect binding. Try: ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedStations}}"

Comment: @YuriTceretian produces the same result. =/

Comment: How do you bind your viewmodel to Window.dataContext? Did you try to run some WPF applications? Maybe it happens because of video adapter (drivers).

Comment: Two questions: are you sure you are not styling your DataGrid anywhere (or any other components, for that matter) in such a way that it could result in a black background? Also, where is your CollectionViewSource located in reference to your DataGrid?

Comment: @JoshuaMiller Yeah, I checked both of these. I had the collectionviewsource defined in a container above, but moved it to the resources section of the datagrid and still the same results.

Comment: Try explicitly assign your collection to DataGrid's ItemsSource. It seems that the problem is not with binding.

Comment: share your viewmodel code.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found is that apparently the DataGrid doesn't play nice with `BindingList`. I have changed to an `ObservableCollection` and it works as expected!